# Generate pairs from list using jinja2 (ansible)

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I am trying to generate pair of hosts from a list of hosts in ansible
I have following inventory

```
[webs]
test
test2
test3
test4
test5
```

How do I generate pairs of hosts, for e.g. test and test2, test3 and test4, test5 and test (repeat from first)

I tried filters like batch, slice and with_items but doesn't seem to work.

Is there a easy way to generate these pairs in ansible?

Comment: What is the use case? Add some context, please.

Comment: I am running connectivity/bandwidth tests between hosts, I prefer pairs with hosts selected randomly, but above will suffice for now.

Comment: Add a piece of code or pseudo code. Do you need to run a play against pairs? or just a single task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can optimize this further.

```
  tasks:
  - set_fact: total_hosts={{groups['webs'] | length }}
  - debug: msg={{groups['webs'] | slice(total_hosts | int // 2) | list}}
    when: "{{total_hosts |int is divisibleby 2}}"
  - debug: msg={{groups['webs'] | slice(total_hosts | int // 2 + 1, fill_with=groups['webs'][0]) | list}}
    when: "{{total_hosts |int is not divisibleby 2}}"
```

Output

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        [
            "test",
            "test2"
        ],
        [
            "test3",
            "test4"
        ],
        [
            "test5",
            "test"
        ]
    ]
}
```

Comment: I came up with this one, but both works equally well

    `hosts_shuffled: "{{groups['webs']|shuffle}}"`

    `# split hosts into two groups, servers and clients`

    `host_lists: "{{hosts_shuffled|slice(2,hosts_shuffled[0])|list}}"`

    `servers: "{{host_lists[0]}}"

    clients: "{{host_lists[1]}}"`